# Как сделать Radial blur с помощью SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, анимация

Такой вопрос, как сделать Radial blur с помощью SVG? Порыв в гугле я понял что либо он в SVG не так называется, либо способа нет...

[image: Radial blur]

Comment: Смотрите в сторону фильтров `feDisplacementMap` и `feTurbulence`. Вот неплохой пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825600/275019

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский я вот например готовлю ответ, это тоже занимает время

Answer (score 16):

Это  конечно **не CSS**, как и в других моих постах последнее время, будем окучивать **WebGL / glsl**, (мало внимания ему уделяется, это заметно по просмотрам)

Я написал маленькую функцию, чтобы вынести за скобки весь **WebGL** код, оставив один лишь фрагментный шейдер на входе:

---

```
document.body.append(webglFilter("https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png",  `

    const int samples = 22;               // кол-во сэмплов
    const float power = 0.001;            // сила эффекта
    const vec2 center = vec2( 0.5, 0.5 ); // центр эффекта

    // матрица поворота
    mat2 rotate2d (float angle) {
        vec2 sc = vec2( sin(angle), cos(angle) );
        return mat2( sc.y, -sc.x, sc.xy );
    }

    vec4 frag (vec2 uv) {

        vec4 color = vec4(0.);                          // аккумулятор
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {

            float dir = sin(length(uv - center)*200.);  // направление повотора
            dir = smoothstep(-.5, .5, dir) - .5;        // делаем из синусоиды сглаженную 
                                                        // ступенчатую функцию

            uv -= center;                               // сдвиг к центру поворота
            uv *= rotate2d( dir * power * float(i) );   // поворот
            uv += center;                               // обратный сдвиг
            color += sample(uv);                        // получить цвет
        }   

        return color / float(samples);                  // взять среднее
    }

`));
```

---

UPD1: попытался лучше повторить эффект на оригинальной картинке

UPD2: добавлена реакция на мышь

UPD3: radial blur теперь применяется плавно

UPD4: на мобилке теперь видно эффекты

UPD5: добавил еще сниппет

---

Версия со ступенчатой функцией поворота

[image: tasty human burgers]

```js
let filter = webglFilter("https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png", `

  const int samples = 22;
  uniform float power;
  uniform vec2 mouse;

  mat2 rotate2d (float angle) {
    vec2 sc = vec2( sin(angle), cos(angle) );
    return mat2( sc.y, -sc.x, sc.xy );
  }

  vec4 frag (vec2 uv) {

    float rotateDir = sin(length(uv - mouse)*1./(0.005 + power*5.));
    rotateDir = smoothstep(-.3, .3, rotateDir)-.5;

    vec2 shiftDir = (uv-mouse)*vec2(-1.0,-1.0);

    vec4 color = vec4(0.);
    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i ++) {
      uv += float(i)/float(samples)*shiftDir*0.01;
      uv -= mouse;      
      uv *= rotate2d( rotateDir * power * float(i)); 
      uv += mouse;
      color += sample(uv) / float(samples);
    } 
    return color;
  }

`);

  let changeCenter = function(e) {
    e = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
    let c = filter.canvas;
    let z = window.getComputedStyle(c).zoom;
    let d = document.documentElement;
    let x = (e.clientX + d.scrollLeft - c.offsetLeft*z) / c.width / z;
    let y = (e.clientY + d.scrollTop - c.offsetTop*z) / c.height / z
    filter.uniform('2f', 'mouse', x, y).apply();
  }

  var applyEffect = (function() {
  
    let power = 0;
    let targ = 0
    let started = 0;

    return function (pow) {
      targ = pow;
      started = new Date().getTime();
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function animate() {
      let dt = new Date().getTime() - started; 
      power += dt * 1e-6 * (targ === 0 ? -1 : 1);
      power = Math[targ === 0 ? 'max' : 'min'](power, targ);
      filter.uniform('1f', 'power', power).apply();
      Math.abs(power-targ) > 1e-7 && requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }

  })();

filter.ready = function() {

  let c = filter.canvas;
  document.body.append(c);
  let z = window.getComputedStyle(c).zoom;
  changeCenter({
      clientX: c.width/2*z,
      clientY: c.height/2*z,
  });
  applyEffect(0.001);
  
  filter.apply();
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => changeCenter(e))
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', e => changeCenter(e))
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => applyEffect(0))
  window.addEventListener('touchend', () => applyEffect(0))
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', () => applyEffect(0.001))
  window.addEventListener('touchstart', () => applyEffect(0.001))
  

}
```

```css
canvas {
  zoom: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script>
function webglFilter(url, fragCode) {
  
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let pid, gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') 
        || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  
  let loader = new Image();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  loader.src = url;
  
  loader.onload = function() { 
    
    canvas.width = loader.width;
    canvas.height = loader.height;

    pid = gl.createProgram();

    shader(`
      attribute vec2 coords;
        void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

    shader(`
      precision highp float;
      uniform sampler2D texture;

      vec4 sample(vec2 uv) {
          return texture2D(texture, uv);
      }

      ${fragCode}

      void main(void) {
          gl_FragColor = frag(vec2( 
            gl_FragCoord.x / ${canvas.width}.,  
            1. - gl_FragCoord.y / ${canvas.height}. 
          ));
      }
    `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(pid);
    gl.useProgram(pid);

    let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "texture");
    gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
 
    filter.ready && filter.ready();
    
    function shader(src, type) {
      let sid = gl.createShader(type);
      gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
      gl.compileShader(sid);
      var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
      gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
      if (message.length > 0) {
        console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
          return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
        }).join('\n'));
        throw message;
      }
    }
  }
  
  let filter = {
    
    canvas: canvas,
    
    ready: null,
    
    uniform: function(type, name, v1, v2, v3, v4) {
      if (!pid)
        throw new Error('image not loaded yet');
      var ul = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, name);
      gl['uniform' + type](ul, v1, v2, v3, v4);
      return filter;
    },
    
    apply: function() {
      if (!pid)
        throw new Error('image not loaded yet');
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
      return filter;
    }
  }
  
  return filter;
}
</script>
```

---

Обычный radial blur:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let filter = webglFilter("https://i.imgur.com/tbmyMTo.jpg", `

  const int samples = 66;
  uniform float power;
  uniform vec2 mouse;

  mat2 rotate2d (float angle) {
    vec2 sc = vec2( sin(angle), cos(angle) );
    return mat2( sc.y, -sc.x, sc.xy );
  }

  vec4 frag (vec2 uv) {

    float rotateDir = length(uv - mouse)*1./(0.005 + power*5.);
    rotateDir = smoothstep(-.3, .3, rotateDir)-.5;

    vec2 shiftDir = (uv-mouse)*vec2(-1.0,-1.0);

    vec4 color = vec4(0.);
    for (int i = 0; i < samples; i ++) {
      uv += float(i)/float(samples)*shiftDir*0.01;
      uv -= mouse;      
      uv *= rotate2d( rotateDir * power * float(i)); 
      uv += mouse;
      color += sample(uv)/float(samples+i);
    } 
    return color*1.5;
  }

`);

  let changeCenter = function(e) {
    e = e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
    let c = filter.canvas;
    let z = window.getComputedStyle(c).zoom;
    let d = document.documentElement;
    let x = (e.clientX + d.scrollLeft - c.offsetLeft*z) / c.width / z;
    let y = (e.clientY + d.scrollTop - c.offsetTop*z) / c.height / z
    filter.uniform('2f', 'mouse', x, y).apply();
  }

  var applyEffect = (function() {
  
    let power = 0;
    let targ = 0
    let started = 0;

    return function (pow) {
      targ = pow;
      started = new Date().getTime();
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function animate() {
      let dt = new Date().getTime() - started; 
      power += dt * 1e-6 * (targ === 0 ? -1 : 1);
      power = Math[targ === 0 ? 'max' : 'min'](power, targ);
      filter.uniform('1f', 'power', power).apply();
      Math.abs(power-targ) > 1e-7 && requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }

  })();

filter.ready = function() {
  
  let c = filter.canvas;
  document.body.append(c);
  let z = window.getComputedStyle(c).zoom;
  changeCenter({
      clientX: c.width/2*z,
      clientY: c.height/2*z,
  });
  applyEffect(0.001);
  
  filter.apply();
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => changeCenter(e))
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', e => changeCenter(e))
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => applyEffect(0))
  window.addEventListener('touchend', () => applyEffect(0))
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', () => applyEffect(0.001))
  window.addEventListener('touchstart', () => applyEffect(0.001))
  

}
```

```css
canvas {
zoom:33%
}
```

```html
<script>
function webglFilter(url, fragCode) {
  
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let pid, gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') 
        || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  
  let loader = new Image();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  loader.src = url;
  
  loader.onload = function() { 
    
    canvas.width = loader.width;
    canvas.height = loader.height;

    pid = gl.createProgram();

    shader(`
      attribute vec2 coords;
        void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
    `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

    shader(`
      precision highp float;
      uniform sampler2D texture;

      vec4 sample(vec2 uv) {
          return texture2D(texture, uv);
      }

      ${fragCode}

      void main(void) {
          gl_FragColor = frag(vec2( 
            gl_FragCoord.x / ${canvas.width}.,  
            1. - gl_FragCoord.y / ${canvas.height}. 
          ));
      }
    `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.linkProgram(pid);
    gl.useProgram(pid);

    let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "texture");
    gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
 
    filter.ready && filter.ready();
    filter.apply();
    
    function shader(src, type) {
      let sid = gl.createShader(type);
      gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
      gl.compileShader(sid);
      var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
      gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
      if (message.length > 0) {
        console.log(src.split('\n').map(function (str, i) {
          return ("" + (1 + i)).padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str
        }).join('\n'));
        throw message;
      }
    }
  }
  
  let filter = {
    
    canvas: canvas,
    
    ready: null,
    
    uniform: function(type, name, v1, v2, v3, v4) {
      if (!pid)
        throw new Error('program not ready');
      var ul = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, name);
      gl['uniform' + type](ul, v1, v2, v3, v4);
      return filter;
    },
    
    apply: function() {
      if (!pid)
        throw new Error('program not ready');
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
      return filter;
    }
  }
  
  return filter;
}
</script>
```

---

[Самая актуальная версия тут](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/ZPWXGM)

Comment: дальше ждём автора вопроса ...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Что не сделаешь ради 200 баллов :D

Comment: ну мышки то нету в мобиле ... я имею ввиду не работает типа mouseover хотя разумеется что и не может работаь

Comment: Немного не то..

Comment: @ЕвгенийСтарцев я не смог на глаз определить анатомию этого эффекта

Answer (score 14):

Не претендую на участие, ибо подхожу по меткам лишь частично, да и реализация - "костыль костыльный". Но, тем не менее, пока не дали ответы с SVG, нативный вариант:

```js
var nDivs = 90;
var oWrap = document.querySelector('div.radial_blur');
var oDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
var oTemp;

/* Раскомментировать, если нужен только эффект, без анимации
while (nDivs--) {
  oTemp = oWrap.querySelector('.radial_blur *:empty').appendChild(oDiv.cloneNode(true));
  oTemp.style.transform = 'rotate(1deg)';
}
*/

/* Код ниже, только для наглядной демонстрации */
function radialBlur() {
  oTemp = oWrap.querySelector('.radial_blur *:empty').appendChild(oDiv.cloneNode(true));
  oTemp.style.transform = 'rotate(1deg)';
  nDivs--;
  if (!nDivs) { clearInterval(nIntervId); }
}
var nIntervId = window.setInterval(radialBlur, 80);
```

```css
.radial_blur {
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 435px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/CQvNGGD_d.jpg?maxwidth=520&shape=thumb&fidelity=high') center/cover;
  /* Можно попробовать с другим изображением
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/cdqfoqZ.png') center/cover; */
}

.radial_blur div {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: .95;
}
```

```html
<div class="radial_blur">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикольно, лови плюс!

Comment: + от меня ..ждём автора вопроса

Comment: смотрел с мобилы работает ...

Comment: если до субботы автор не выберет от какой то ответ ...то отмечу этот ответ решением

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский спасибо. Но, я прошу Вас выбрать более достойные примеры. Ребята продвигают технологии, когда я пользуюсь нативными "костылями" (за которые нормальные фронтэндщики могут и побить :-) . Будущее за технологиями, а я лишь показал, что "хоть и криво, но возможно".

Comment: Как выбрать ) к примеру мне твой нравится, ну и так же два остальных тоже ...блин

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский я здесь сижу, чтобы подглядывать, резко выпрыгивать и показывать))) В общем, для удовольствия)) Самая большая награда - это, когда кусок твоего кода используют даже не допиливая (хотя, это и расслабляет вопрошающих). Пока у меня нет стоящих вопросов, а так бы надо замутить, да поделиться репой незаслуженной))

Answer (score 11):

### Вариант SVG

Конечный вид очень сильно зависит от выбранной картинки.
 При одинаковой схеме решения: последовательное применении радиальных градиентов, набора SVG фильтров, всё равно приходится тонко регулировать атрибуты всех SVG компонентов, чтобы получить требуемые эффекты.

- У радиальных градиентов регулируется атрибуты `cx="0.5" cy="0.55"
  r="0.16"` для получения центра фокусировки и придания тунельной
  переспективы.
- У фильтров регулируется  `baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"`  Чем меньше
  цифры тем больше искажение.  `seed="12"`- коэффициент начального
  искажения
  `scale="30"` - коэффициент увеличения искажения

**Добавлена анимация искажения при наведении мыши**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="900" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid gray;" >  

 <defs>
    <mask id="msk1"  > 
   <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%"  />
 
  <circle stroke="black"  fill="white" cx="450" cy="300" r="450" stroke-width="0" />
  <circle stroke="black"  fill="white" cx="450" cy="300" r="350" stroke-width="0" />
    
 </mask> 
 
 <filter id="filter1">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="12"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <filter id="goovey">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.015"  numOctaves="3" result="warpper"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="warpper" type="hueRotate" values="0" >
                <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="values" values="0;150;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseout"/> 
          </feColorMatrix>
          <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
  </filter>
  <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="0.5" cy="0.55" r="0.16"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="15%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="1" />    
    <stop offset="55%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="1"/>
    
    </radialGradient> 
  
     <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0.5" cy="0.6" r="0.06"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.9" />    
  </radialGradient> 
 
  </defs> 
 
  <g> 
  <image id="img1"   filter="url(#goovey)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ty5b.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
   <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="url(#grad2)"  fill-opacity="0.6" />
  </g>  
 </svg>  
</div>
```

**Второй вариант.**

Другая картинка и настройки немного другие

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="900" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

 <defs>
    <mask id="msk1"  > 
   <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%"  />
 
  <circle stroke="black"  fill="white" cx="450" cy="300" r="450" stroke-width="0" />
  <circle stroke="black"  fill="white" cx="450" cy="300" r="350" stroke-width="0" />
    
 </mask> 
 
 <filter id="filter1">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="12"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <filter id="goovey">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01"  numOctaves="3" result="warpper"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="warpper" type="hueRotate" values="0" >
                <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="values" values="0;150;0" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseout"/> 
          </feColorMatrix>
          <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="30" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="0.5" cy="0.6" r="0.19"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="52%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.5" />    
    <stop offset="85%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
    
  </radialGradient> 
  
   <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0.5" cy="0.6" r="0.06"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.9" />    
  </radialGradient> 
 </defs> 
 <g> 
  <image id="img1"   filter="url(#goovey)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Mpe.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
   <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="url(#grad1)"  fill-opacity="0.7" />
 </g>  
 
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Третий вариант**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="900" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

 <defs>
    <mask id="msk1"> 
   <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%"  />
 
  <circle stroke="black"  fill="white" cx="450" cy="300" r="450" stroke-width="0" />
  <circle stroke="black"  fill="white" cx="450" cy="300" r="350" stroke-width="0" />
    
 </mask> 
 
 <filter id="filter1">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="12"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <filter id="goovey">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01"  numOctaves="1" result="warpper"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="warpper" type="hueRotate" values="0" >
                <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="values" values="0;150;0" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseout"/> 
          </feColorMatrix>
          <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="30" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
    </filter>
  <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="0.5" cy="0.6" r="0.25"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="52%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.8" />    
    <stop offset="85%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
    
  </radialGradient> 
  
    <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0.5" cy="0.6" r="0.06"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.9" />    
    </radialGradient> 
 
  </defs> 
 
 <g> 
   <image id="img1"   filter="url(#goovey)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia9YO.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
     <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="url(#grad1)"  fill-opacity="0.6" />
 </g>  
 

 
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Update 04.03.2019 г.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Добавлена комплексная маска, которая обрезает изображение по
  окружности.
- К разным частям маски применены разные радиальные градиенты
- К градиентам применена анимация изменения радиуса градиента,
  создающая туннельный эффект с фокусировкой на отдельном человеке

  *Для демонстрации эффекта, откройте сниппет в полном формате и наведите курсор*

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="900" height="600" viewBox="0 0 900 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  

 <defs>
    <mask id="msk1"  > 
 <!--   <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%"   />  -->
     <circle cx="450" cy="300" r="400" stroke-width="100" stroke="url(#grad2)" fill="url(#grad1)" />
  </mask> 
 
 <filter id="filter1">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" seed="12"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"/>
  </filter>    

  <filter id="goovey">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.015"  numOctaves="3" result="warpper"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="warpper" type="hueRotate" values="0" >
                <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="values" values="0;150;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseout"/> 
          </feColorMatrix>
          <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
  </filter>
  <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="0.35" cy="0.48" r="0.14"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="15%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="1" />    
    <stop offset="55%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="1"/>
    
        <animate
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName="r"
    values="0.2;0.035;0.2"
    dur="20s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    end="svg1.mouseout"/> 
  
   </radialGradient>  
     
     <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0.5" cy="0.6" r="0.06"  spreadMethod="reflect">
    <stop offset="2%" stop-color="white"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#BED0DC" stop-opacity="0.9" />    
  </radialGradient> 
 
  </defs> 
  
  <image id="img1" mask="url(#msk1)"   filter="url(#goovey)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp46o.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
    
 </svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошие попытки, ставлю плюс

Comment: Очень интересный вариант!

Comment: А можно попросить авторов ответов поменять PNG на JPEG? Сейчас картинки весят очень много и чудовищно долго грузятся, не у всех в мире гигабитные интернеты

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ↑

Comment: @andreymal вы имеете в виду картинки в сниппетах? я сделаю.., когда у компа буду

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а у меня 1Mb, и полёт совершенно не нормальный. И это я ещё в Петербурге, а на каком-нибудь Дальнем Востоке даже 0.5Mb это великое счастье

Comment: @Alexandr_TT [да в любом бизнес-центре](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqxXZ.jpg). Также советую прочитать это https://pikabu.ru/story/skaz_o_norilskom_internete_ili_tsenite_to_chto_imeete_6519341

Comment: +, но это немного не то.