# По-строковое суммирование данных по заданному диапазону [JS, canvas]

Tags: javascript, canvas

Не получается реализовать функцию по-строкового суммирования данных по заданному диапазону. Данными являются значения синего канала пикселей.

На примере этой картинки:

[image: пример]

На выходе должен получить:

> [**0** - 255] [**1** - 510] [**2** - 765] [**3** - 765] [**4** - 510]
>
> [**5** - 765] [**6** - 765] [**7** - 765] [**8** - 510] [**9** - 255]
>
> [**10** - 510] [**11** - 765] [**12** - 1020] [**13** - 765] [**14** -
>   765]

**Проблема** заключается в корректном подсчёте при переходе на следующую строку, то есть, чтобы пиксель **4**, при диапазоне [-2; 2] суммировался только с предыдущими двумя значениями (пиксели 2 и 3). А пиксель **5** (начало новой строки) игнорировал предыдущие пиксели, находящиеся в первой строке.

Помогите подправить имеющийся код.

Функция:

```
function getRowSumOfBlueChannels(Array, Counter, Width, MinSigmaValue, MaxSigmaValue){
var sum = 0;
var blueChannels = [];
var numRow = 1;
blueChannels = getBlueChannels(Array);

        for(var sigma = MinSigmaValue; sigma <= MaxSigmaValue; sigma++){

            if(blueChannels[Counter + sigma] !== undefined){
                if( (Counter + sigma) < Width * numRow){  // ошибка тут

                    sum += blueChannels[Counter + sigma];

                } else {
                    numRow++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    return sum;
}
```

---

**UPD** Реализовал функцию, решил хранить значения сумм в массиве.

Если кому интересно моё решение:

```
function getRowSumOfBlueChannel(Array, Width, Height, MinSigmaValue, MaxSigmaValue){
var sum = 0;
var blueChannels = [];

blueChannels = getBlueChannels(Array);

    var sumValues = [];

        for(var numRow = 0; numRow < Height; numRow++){
            for(var i = numRow * Width; i < Width + (numRow * Width); i++){

                for(var sigma = MinSigmaValue; sigma <= MaxSigmaValue; sigma++){

                    if( blueChannels[i + sigma] !== undefined){ // игнорируем отрицательные знаения

                        if( ((i + sigma) >= Width + ((numRow - 1) * Width )) && ((i + sigma) < Width + (numRow * Width))  ){ 
                            sum += blueChannels[i + sigma];
                        }   

                    }
                }
                sumValues[i] = sum;

                alert(i + " | " + sumValues[i] );
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

    return sumValues;
}
```

Comment: вся идея в этой проверке `let differentRows = !colors[index + offset] ||   Math.floor(index/width) !== Math.floor((index+offset)/width);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не смог понять Вашу идею и сделал как сделал:

вся идея в этой проверке `let differentRows = !colors[index + offset] || Math.floor(index/width) !== Math.floor((index+offset)/width);`

```js
let kernel = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2];

let black = [0,0,0];
let white = [255,255,255];
let red = [255,0,0];
let blue = [0,0,255];
let cyan = [0,255,255];
let yellow = [255,255,0];
let magenta = [255,0,255];

let width = 5;
let height = 3;

let colors = [
  red,   white, black,   blue,  white,
  blue,  blue,  magenta, black, yellow,
  white, black, blue,    cyan,  white
];

let sum = colors.map((value, index) => 
  kernel.map(offset => get(index, offset))
        .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0));

function get(index, offset) {
  let differentRows = !colors[index + offset] || 
                      Math.floor(index/width) !== Math.floor((index+offset)/width);
  return differentRows ? 0 : colors[index + offset][2];
}



console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, у Вас интересное компактное решение. Некоторые методы (и особенности синтаксиса) мне пока не знакомы, есть повод разобраться и понять!

Comment: @azatt задавайте вопросы, с радостью отвечу

Comment: @azatt для реального изображения это можно сделать при помощи видеокарты во фрагментном шейдере, там, если не считать управляющего кода, это можно сделать в 2-3 строчки =), так устроен blur, только он берет значения не только справа и слева но и сверху и снизу и не только синий а весь цвет

Comment: @azatt https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951405/188366