# Можно ли создать в canvas blur эффект на фото при mousemove?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, blur

Можно ли создать на canvas библиотеке [Konva.js](https://konvajs.org/) (или на каком-то другом) blur эффект на фото при mousemove?

Читал документацию к Konva js, но ничего подходящего не нашел. Искал примеры, достойных примеров не нашел.

Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/by_olegovichs/1nxpu5bz/) с встроенным фильтром в canvas `ctx.filter = 'blur(5px)';`.

Comment: забыл добавить. важна поддержка IE11+

Comment: такое легко сделать на webgl, примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951405/188366

Comment: Вот же https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Blur.html. И дальше как в вашем примере. Почему не подошло?

Comment: Эффект тот, но мне нужно часть фото блюрить, а не всю.
например, рисовать blur effect`ом.
не пойму, как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно можно было бы взять библиотеку, но и вручную можно добится неплохих результатов, а заодно и познакомится поближе с обработкой изображений.

Это решение использунт прямые манипуляции с пикселями.

Применяем ко всем пикселям области, которую необходимо заблюрить, так называемое "ядро свертки" ([convolution kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing))) - основа основ в обработке изображений.

[Вот тут подробно про это написано а так же визуализировано](http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/)

Запустите сниппет заново, если картинка не показательная (они псевдослучайные), в сниппете реализовано рисование блюром, как Вы просили в комментариях...

```js
let s = 44; // size of area to be blurred
let kernel =[[0,0,1,0,0],
             [0,1,2,1,0],
             [1,2,3,2,1],
             [0,1,2,1,0],
             [0,0,1,0,0]];

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let total = kernel.flatMap(i => i).reduce((a, i) => a + Math.abs(i)), 
    ks = (kernel.length-1)/2, // half of kernel size - 1 (pixels around center)
    s2 = s/2, // half size of area to be blurred
    sks2 = s+ks*2; // size of area of pixels needed to be processed

img.onload = e => ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
addEventListener('mousedown', e => draw = true)
addEventListener('mouseup', e => draw = false)
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if (!window.draw) return;
  var input = ctx.getImageData(e.layerX-s2-ks, e.layerY-s2-ks, sks2, sks2);
  var output = ctx.createImageData(s, s); 
  for (var x = 0; x < s; x++) 
    for (var y = 0; y < s; y++) 
      handlePixel(input, output, x, y)
  ctx.putImageData(output, e.layerX - s2, e.layerY - s2) 
})

function handlePixel(i, o, x, y) {
    let offset = (y * s + x) * 4; // offset in output data (4=rgba)
    for (var kx = -ks; kx <= ks; kx++) 
        for (var ky = -ks; ky <= ks; ky++) {
            let off = ((y+ks) * sks2 + (x+ks) + kx + ky * sks2) * 4; //offset in input
            for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++) 
                o.data[offset + n] += kernel[kx+ks][ky+ks] * i.data[off+n] / total;
        }
    o.data[offset + 3] = 255; // always opaque
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<img id="img" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" crossOrigin="anonymous">
<style>body{margin:0}img {display:none;}</style>
```

PS: от бага по краям надо подумать как избавиться...

Comment: спасибо большое.
буду разбираться

Comment: конечно использовать фреймворк избавляет от размышлений, однако блюр очень просто реализуется руками. спрашивайте если что

Comment: спасибо!
да, конечно.

Comment: на мобильном устройстве (iphone se, ios 12.3.1) блюр отрабатывает как-то [странно](http://prntscr.com/oejamt)

Comment: похоже проблема со считыванием значений пикселей, вероятно crossorigin проблема

Comment: base64 не помогает.

Comment: @ВадимСтебаков а можете значения вывести на экран и узнать что он там считывает?

Comment: @ВадимСтебаков хотя судя по области сверху на облаках он что-то там размыл

Comment: если один раз провести пальцем по экрану, то нормально (1), но если многократно проводить, то выходит вот так (2)
[вот](http://prntscr.com/oejr06)

Comment: @ВадимСтебаков а скиньте ссылку на этот пен

Comment: https://codepen.io/by_olegovichs/pen/bPJaex?editors=1010

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96152/discussion-between---and-stranger-in-the-q).