# Круглый прогресс-бар с эффектом движения воды

Tags: javascript, canvas, progress-bar, webgl

Кто знает как можно реализовать такой круглый прогресс-бар с эффектом воды как в центральной части этого сайта https://asmobius.co.jp/

[image: скринвидео]

Comment: скриншот хотя бы добавьте

Comment: @StrangerintheQ жду твоего ответа вечером :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я отозвал свой голос.А так сайт клёвый красивые эффекты.Жаль что написано на wordpress.

Comment: А  не быстро сможете сварганить?))

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, я добавил аж гифку.

Comment: @Qwertiy теперь красиво смотрится.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Подобные эффекты возможно сделать использовав фрагментный шейдер, в котором вычисляется каждый пиксель, в зависимости от положения слайдера.

Здесь наблюдается 2 слоя:

Один - 2 картинки одна поверх другой, между которыми происходит переход при помощи прозрачности  картинки и сдвиг в противоположные стороны.

Второй - кольцо, внутри которого так же находятся обе картинки, с границей, определяемой значением слайдера + искажение текстурных координат, для имитации эффекта воды.

Для реализации я взял и скретил свои же старые ответы: [эффект воды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992563/188366) и [огненное кольцо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992930/188366)

```js
let pid, timeLocarion, valueLocation, 
    v = Math.PI, value = Math.PI, gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

loadTexture(0, "https://picsum.photos/id/88/400/400")
loadTexture(1, "https://picsum.photos/id/77/400/400")

addEventListener('wheel', s => {
  value = value - Math.sign(s.deltaY)*0.1;
})

pid = gl.createProgram();
shader(`attribute vec2 c;void main(void){gl_Position=vec4(c,0.,1.);}`,gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

shader(`
  precision lowp float;
  uniform vec2 size; // размер стороны квадрата этого беспредела
  uniform float time; // время
  uniform float val; // значение слайдера, от минус пи до пи
  uniform sampler2D tex1; // первая текстура
  uniform sampler2D tex2; // вторая ткестура
  
  // эффект воды
  vec2 waterEffect(vec2 uv) {
    float s = 0.;
    vec2 p = uv;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      vec2 adjc = p;
      float theta = 2. * 3.1415 / 11.*float(i);
      adjc.x += cos(theta)*time*.1 + time * .03;
      adjc.y -= sin(theta)*time*.1 - time * .07;
      float a = adjc.x*cos(theta) - adjc.y*sin(theta);
      s += cos(a*15.) * 3.1415;
    }
    return p += sin(s)*.01;
  }

  void main(void) {
    // текстурные координаты
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / size.xy;
    // сдвигаем текстурные координаты, чтобы отсчет начинался от центра экрана
    vec2 c = uv - .5;
    // делаем из прямоугольника квадрат, чтобы был круг а не эллипс
    c.x *= size.x/size.y;
    
    // если фрагмент вне кольца
    if (abs(sqrt(dot(c, c)) - .4) > .05) {
      // смешиваем 2 текстуры в пропорциях в зависимости от положения слайдера
      float t = val/6.28 + .5;
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, vec2(uv.x + t*.1, uv.y))*t 
                   + texture2D(tex2, vec2(uv.x - t*.1, uv.y))*(1.-t);
                   
    } else { // само кольцо
    
       vec2 water = waterEffect(uv);
       // тут небольшой хак с арктангенсом, обратите внимание на порядок следования 
       /// аргументов, у нормального арктангенса первым аргументом идет y а вторым x, 
       // перемена мест аргументов меняет местами оси системы координат - теперь 
       //граница на кольце не слева а сверху
       if (atan(c.x, -c.y) > val) //справа или слева от границы ?
          gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, water);
       else 
          gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex2, water);
    
    }
  }
`, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1,3,-1,-1,3,-1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "c");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);


timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
valueLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'val');
let sizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'size');
gl.uniform2f(sizeLocation, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight)
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function loadTexture(i, url) {
  let loader = new Image();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  loader.src = url;
  loader.onload = function() {
    let texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, loader);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(pid, "tex"+i), i);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
  }
}

function draw(t) {
  let speed = Math.max(0.0001, Math.abs(value-v)*0.1);
  if (v < value) v = Math.min(value, v+speed);
  if (v > value) v = Math.max(value, v-speed);
  let val = v;
  while (val < -Math.PI) val += Math.PI*2;
  while (val > Math.PI) val -= Math.PI*2;
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, t / 1000);
  gl.uniform1f(valueLocation, val);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n").map((str, i) => ("" + (1 + i))
                   .padStart(4, "0") + ": " + str).join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Stranger in the Q скажите а почему урлы с картинками не заменяются на локальные в image папке?

Comment: Stranger in the Q  я попыталась загрузить фото на какие то сервисы, чтобы у картинки появился такой же урл. Но он все равно не отображает их почему то. Пробовала и на яндекс загрузить картинку и даже с размером canvasa но скрипт их все равно не видит

Comment: какие параметры в скрипте надо изменить чтобы сама эта водяная линия стала толще?

Comment: Stranger in the Q возьмите на доработку проект, вы не плохо управляетесь с шейдерами. Я хочу решать задачу поэтапно. Для начала сделать хотя бы просто круг без картинки фоном. Дайте связь с вами обсудить заказ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не понимаю почему этот овтет не набрал +50 голосов.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов видимо все же мало кого это интересует