# Изменение цвета блока по мере прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как можно сделать, чтобы по мере прокрутки страницы полоса меню постепенно переходила от одного цвета в другой?

```css
section {
  height: 1000px;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, red);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Или такой вариант:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  var docHeight = $(document).height();
  var winScrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docScrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
  var scrollPercent = 100 * winScrolled / (docHeight - winHeight);
  $('#main').css('width', scrollPercent + "%");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 1000px;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

section:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, red);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

Comment: разных цветов же надо

Comment: @Sevastopol' в любом случае двигать градиент -решение, можно радугу

Comment: @Sevastopol' у меня где то есть очень похожий ответ, но на телефоне не найду

Answer (score 7):

Как вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            let step = 100;
                let x = 255;
                let y = 0;
                let z = 0;
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() < 255){
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0 + $(window).scrollTop();
                    z = 255;
                }else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 255 && $(window).scrollTop() < 510){
                    x = 0;
                    y = 255;
                    z = 255 - $(window).scrollTop() + 255;
                } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 510 && $(window).scrollTop() < 765){
                    x = 0 + $(window).scrollTop() - 510;
                    y = 255;
                    z = 0;
                } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 765 && $(window).scrollTop() < 1120){
                    x = 255;
                    y = 255 - $(window).scrollTop() + 765;
                    z = 0;
                } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1120 && $(window).scrollTop() < 1375){
                    x = 0;
                    y = 255 - $(window).scrollTop();
                    z = 255;
                } else {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    z = 255;
                }
                let param = 'rgb('+x+', '+y+', '+z+')';
                $("#main").css('background', param);

        });
});
```

```css
    body {
        height: 1000px;
    }
    section {
        height: auto;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #main {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
    }
    #boddy{
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boddy">
<div id="main"></div>
<article>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</article>
</div>
```

Вариант с переливающимся градиентом:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                let step = 100;
                    let x = 255;
                    let y = 0;
                    let z = 0;
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() < 255){
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0 + $(window).scrollTop();
                        z = 255;
                    }else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 255 && $(window).scrollTop() < 510){
                        x = 0;
                        y = 255;
                        z = 255 - $(window).scrollTop() + 255;
                    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 510 && $(window).scrollTop() < 765){
                        x = 0 + $(window).scrollTop() - 510;
                        y = 255;
                        z = 0;
                    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 765 && $(window).scrollTop() < 1120){
                        x = 255;
                        y = 255 - $(window).scrollTop() + 765;
                        z = 0;
                    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1120 && $(window).scrollTop() < 1375){
                        x = 0;
                        y = 255 - $(window).scrollTop();
                        z = 255;
                    } else {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        z = 255;
                    }
                    let param = 'rgb('+x+', '+y+', '+z+')';
                    $("#main").css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right, '+param+', red)');

            });
    });
```

```css
    body {
        height: 1000px;
    }
    section {
        height: auto;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #main {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
    }
    #boddy{
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boddy">
<div id="main"></div>
<article>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</article>
</div>
```

Вариант с отслеживанием мышки и сменой градиента:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).mousemove(function(event){
            let xz = event.clientX;
            let yz = event.clientY;

            xz = xz + yz;

                let step = 100;
                    let x = 255;
                    let y = 0;
                    let z = 0;

                    let x1 = 255;
                    let y1 = 0;
                    let z1 = 0;

                    if (xz > 0 && xz < 255){
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0 + xz;
                        z = 255;
                    } else if (xz > 255 && xz < 510){
                        x = 0;
                        y = 255;
                        z = 255 - xz + 255;
                    } else if (xz > 510 && xz < 765){
                        x = 0 + xz - 510;
                        y = 255;
                        z = 0;
                    } else if (xz > 765 && xz < 1020){
                        x = 255;
                        y = 255 - xz + 765;
                        z = 0;
                    } else if (xz > 1020 && xz < 1275){
                        x = 255;
                        y = 0;
                        z = 0 + xz - 1020;
                    } else if(xz > 1275 && xz < 1530){
                        x = 255 - xz +1275;
                        y = 0;
                        z = 255;
                    } else {
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0 + xz -1530;
                        z = 255;
                    }
                    if (yz > 0 && yz < 255){
                        x1 = 0;
                        y1 = 0 + yz;
                        z1 = 255;
                    }else if (yz > 255 && yz < 510){
                        x1 = 0;
                        y1 = 255;
                        z1 = 255 - yz + 255;
                    } else if (yz > 510 && yz < 765){
                        x1 = 0 + yz - 510;
                        y1 = 255;
                        z1 = 0;
                    } else if (yz > 765 && yz < 1120){
                        x1 = 255;
                        y1 = 255 - yz + 765;
                        z1 = 0;
                    } else if (yz > 1120 && yz < 1375){
                        x1 = 0;
                        y1 = 255 - yz;
                        z1 = 255;
                    } else {
                        x1 = 0;
                        y1 = 0;
                        z1 = 255;
                    }
                    let param = 'rgb('+x+', '+y+', '+z+')';
                    let param1 = 'rgb('+x1+', '+y1+', '+z1+')';
                    $("#main").css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right, '+param+', '+param1+')');

            });
    });
```

```css
    body {
        height: 1000px;
    }
    section {
        height: auto;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #main {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
    }
    #boddy{
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boddy">
<div id="main"></div>
<article>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</article>
</div>
```

Адаптивный вариант отслеживания курсора и смены градиента.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).mousemove(function(event){
            let xz = event.clientX;
            let yz = event.clientY;

            var xwin1 = $(window).width() / 100;
            var ywin1 = $(window).height() / 100;

            xz = Math.round(xz / xwin1);
            yz = Math.round(yz / ywin1);
            let zz = Math.abs((xz+yz)/2);
            zz = Math.round((zz * 350) / 100);

            if (Math.abs(xz-yz) < 25){
                yz = Math.abs(100-yz);
            }

            let param = 'hsl('+zz+', '+xz+'%, '+yz+'%)';
            let param1 = 'hsl('+zz+', '+yz+'%, '+xz+'%)';
            $("#main").css('background', 'linear-gradient(to right, '+param+', '+param1+')');

            });
    });
```

```css
    body {
        height: 1000px;
    }
    section {
        height: auto;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #main {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #boddy{
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boddy">
<div id="main"></div>
<article>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: сделайте цвет через hsl - избавитесь от массива

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, Кстати точно. Очень хорошее замечание. Сейчас перекушу и сделаю. Там можно же будет даже и пошире диапазон сделать, да покрасивше )))

Comment: я начал так делать, но Вы раньше ответили :)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Если хотите - можете выложить ) Я в принципе за рейтингом не гонюсь. ))) Да и что-то он не прибавляется у меня сегодня больше. Если нет, то обязательно сделаю после перекуса )

Comment: я не сторонник дубликатов, 200- дневной потолок за. плюсы

Comment: @Sevastopol' Как по мне, то SO должен быть чистым альтруизмом ))) Иначе начнётся потом из разряда - сделаю, если заплатите. И все мы понимаем, к чему это приведёт.

Comment: @Sevastopol' да, но если по честному, это стоит дороже, пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1019102/188366 и то, вариант за который мне заплатили был более продвинутый, это только затравочка

Comment: @Sevastopol' на самом деле, по гафике - я в самом начале пути ..

Comment: @Denis640Kb Салам ! А там незя как нить сделать что бы цвет независел от высоты скрола ?

Comment: и кстати если о репе то на SO есть ограничение - 200 балов и всё потом не засчитывается ...а плюсики я все ответу которые увидел поставил

Comment: @MaximLensky Да надо почистить. Отходил чаёвничать ) Вариант добавил. С нормальной шириной экрана получше смотрится.

Answer (score 6):

Моя версия просиходящего:

```js
addEventListener('scroll',() => {
  let hue = content.getBoundingClientRect().top/22;
  main.style.background = `linear-gradient(45deg, white, hsl(${hue},100%,50%))`;
});
```

```css
body {  margin: 0; }

section {
  height: 20000px;
  background: linear-gradient(88deg, white 49%, #ddd 51%);
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, red);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<article id="content">
  <section></section>
</article>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/eYOXBbE

Comment: Эх, жалко плюсов нет ещё 4 часа. Ну ничего. Я Вас запомнил )))

Comment: Таким образом получается перевести одно число в цвет, без плясок вокруг rgb. При линейно изменяющемся входном параметре (hue) получается плавный переход цвета, думайте про этот параметр как про поворот палитры...

Comment: @Sevastopol' здорово что это есть из коробки, в css, а вообще - интерполяцию цвета удобно делать именно в этом представлении

Comment: @Stranger in the Q У меня, благодаря Вашему варианту ещё идея появилась ))) Сейчас попробую реализовать.

Comment: @Sevastopol' вот действительно интересный экземпляр http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~dag/CUBEHELIX/

Comment: @Sevastopol' Ох, как по мне, так вообще бы с ней не связываться ) Ну да, ещё 4 часа не будет плюсов =(((

Comment: @Denis640Kb в графике очень интересные подходы и алгоритмы =)

Comment: @Sevastopol' слона надо есть по чуть чуть

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Чур хобот мой ))) На мой субъективный взгляд, алгоритмов больше в backendе )

Comment: @Denis640Kb https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/raymarchingdf/raymarchingdf.htm https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/fbm/fbm.htm

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Добавил ещё один вариант адаптивный в процентах от экрана )  Что касается ссылок - я с рисованием, графикой и музыкой, на "Здравствуйте Ваше преосвященство". )

Comment: @Denis640Kb я к графике с бэкэнда и пришел =)

Comment: @Denis640Kb по первой ссылке коллекция работ, которые товарищ сделал без использования классического моделирования, все картинки - огромный шейдер, т.е. на 99% математика и алгоритмы, и это не картинки, а анимированные 3d сцены

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Ну так это тем более требует знаний рисования как минимум ))) Да я карандаш нормальный даже нарисовать не смогу, какие бы я алгоритмы не строил ))) Тут нужно "видение" творческое )))

Comment: @Denis640Kb https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JnCkF62gkOY